# Selenium --> How to select a button from a li class [Java]

Tags: java, selenium

On my website I have a button where I have to hover over a button to 'unlock'  4 other menu choices.

I want to hover over my menu, which goes ok, but I cant seem to locate the element that I want to choose after the hover-action. The code in the console disappears after hovering with my mouse from the button, so I cant locate the button by xpath or css. Also the code of the 4 choices are the same, the only thing what differs them is the data-name parameter.

Plusknop (main  button, after hovering over this the upcoming 4 choices are visible)

- 'Contact aanmaken'i want to click this one
- 'Widget aanmaken'
- 'Contactmoment toevoegen'
- 'Zaak aanmaken'

  ```
   WebElement plusknop = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".top-bar-create-case"));

   Actions action = new Actions(driver);

   action.moveToElement(plusknop).build().perform();

  WebElement contact =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("/html/body/div[1]/zs-intern/div[1]/zs-contextual-action-menu/zs-contextual-action-menu-button/div[2]/ul/li[data-name=\"contact\"]"));

  contact.click();
  ```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector
>   expression
>   "/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-intern/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-contextual-action-menu/zs-contextual-action-menu-button/div[2]/ul/li[.="contact"]"
>   is invalid: InvalidSelectorError:
>   '/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-intern/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-contextual-action-menu/zs-contextual-action-menu-button/div[2]/ul/li[.="contact"]'
>   is not a valid selector:
>   "/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-intern/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png)/zs-contextual-action-menu/zs-contextual-action-menu-button/div[2]/ul/li[.="contact"]"

All four menu options have the same xpath. The only thing what differs them is the 'data-name'. That is what I added manually to the code at the end of the code. I want to select the one with the data-name 'contact'

I really can not add the code becuase it is impossible to select it as it disappears when I want to copy the code. Here is a more extended code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8eWu.png).

Comment: Please add relevant code in the question as _code_, not as screenshots.

Comment: It is just a little bit hard to understand your question. It would help a lot if you clarify the following:

1. Do you have access to change the html code, to include ID's for your desired element?
2. What does 'flex popup menu list' really mean?
3. Include the code, as a code snippet in the question, instead of a screenshot link.

Comment: Also, how do you locate the element manually? does it have a specific name? Placement in the DOM? What seperates it from the other elements?

Comment: I updated the intro. thank you so much for the responses. I am a bit of a noob so excuse me.

Comment: You are using cssSelector with an xPath. The exception is giving a valid error message: Given css selector expression ... is invalid.

Comment: That is an Css selector Dakshina. My problem is why he wont find it. Are my parameters inside the dataname 'contact'written wrong ? What are your solutions? I tried so long to solve this!

Comment: @Erman it is *not* a CSS selector. For example "/html/body" is a Xpath where as "html > body" is the corresponding CSS selector.